# Where download older versions of Android Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, android-facebook

Can anyone tell me where I can download older versions of Android Facebook SDK? Mainly lower to 3.0 version . 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Facebook SDK for Android](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) is open source and hosted at GitHub. Simply checkout a revision that it old enough to suit your purposes.